# ttk.Notebook tab with Canvas, expanding to fill the window

Tags: canvas, tkinter, resize, ttk

I have a simple GUI that has three Frames. One of those frames is a Notebook frame containing a canvas. The problem is the Notebook frame doesn't expand to fit the window. I've tried all different combinations of grid() and pack(). Nothing seems to work for me. So I've finally come here. I hope someone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Included is a stripped down version of my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
import ttk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")
window.title("Notebook Test")

options_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

def doNothing():
    pass

leftFrame = Frame(window)
tabFrame = Frame(window)
statusFrame = Frame(window)

leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")
tabFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nw")
statusFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

Xlabel = Label(leftFrame, text="X Function", anchor=N)
Xlabel.pack()
x_var = StringVar(leftFrame)
x_menu = ttk.Combobox(leftFrame, textvariable=x_var)
x_menu["values"] = options_list
x_menu.current(0)
x_menu.pack()

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(tabFrame)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Default One")
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Default Two")
tab_control.grid()

canvas1 = Canvas(tab1, bg="blue")
canvas2 = Canvas(tab2, bg="green")

canvas1.grid()
canvas2.grid()

tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", doNothing, True)
tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", doNothing, True)
tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", doNothing, True)

status = Label(statusFrame, text = "Status:", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(fill=X, expand=True)

window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Here is a picture of what I currently have:

[Notebook Frame that won't resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz87v.png)

As you can see, the "blue" part should fill much more of the window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `height` and `width` to your notebook widget:

```
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(tabFrame,height=480,width=495)
```

To have your tab scales, bind a `<Configure>` event to your root window:

```
def conf(event):
    tab_control.config(height=window.winfo_height(),width=window.winfo_width()-145)

window.bind("<Configure>",conf)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Now I just need to set some limits. But you're a life saver!

Comment: @comport9 Please mark this as the answer, if you think it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue, changed some `.grid()` to `.pack(...)` as below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")
window.title("Notebook Test")

options_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

def doNothing(event): # added event argument
    pass

leftFrame = Frame(window)
tabFrame = Frame(window)
statusFrame = Frame(window)

leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")
tabFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew") # changed "nw" to "nsew"
statusFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

Xlabel = Label(leftFrame, text="X Function", anchor=N)
Xlabel.pack()
x_var = StringVar(leftFrame)
x_menu = ttk.Combobox(leftFrame, textvariable=x_var)
x_menu["values"] = options_list
x_menu.current(0)
x_menu.pack()

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(tabFrame)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Default One")
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Default Two")
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both') # changed from grid() to pack()

canvas1 = Canvas(tab1, bg="blue")
canvas2 = Canvas(tab2, bg="green")

canvas1.pack(fill='both', expand=1) # changed from grid() to pack()
canvas2.pack(fill='both', expand=1) # changed from grid() to pack()

tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", doNothing, True)
tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", doNothing, True)
tab_control.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", doNothing, True)

status = Label(statusFrame, text = "Status:", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(fill=X, expand=True)

window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # changed row 1 to 0
window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped with the width, but the height wasn't resizing.

Comment: Strange! It works in my Windows 7.  Did you make the change on `window.grid_rowconfigure(...)`?

Comment: @acw1668 I've encountered the same issue with not resizable ttk.notebook and tried pack() as well and it does help with horizontal scale only, at least on Win10 + python2.7